# Wicket AjaxLink isLinkEnabled() = false renders a clickable span

Tags: java, html, wicket

I'm using Wicket 6.11 and have come across a strange error.  I have wicket AjaxLinks with icons inside of them all over a large application, whose isLinkEnabled() can return false based on various circumstances.  When it does, it renders the link as disabled as you would expect (a span tag with an em tag inside it), but when I click on the icon, the event still fires!

Example code:

```
AjaxLink<Object> button = new AjaxLink<Object>( "editLocationButton" ) {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public void onClick( AjaxRequestTarget p_target ) {
    // do things
  }

  /**
   * @see org.apache.wicket.markup.html.link.AbstractLink#isLinkEnabled()
   */
  @Override
  protected boolean isLinkEnabled() {
    return super.isLinkEnabled() && getSelectedLocation() != null;
  }
};
```

Html file:

```
            <td style="width:0%">
                <a href="#" wicket:id="editLocationButton" class="editButton iconButton">
                    <wicket:message key="button.edit.location"></wicket:message>
                </a>
            </td>
```

Rendered html when disabled:

```
<td style="width:0%">
    <span class="editButton iconButton" id="editLocationButton7b6"><em>

    </em></span>
</td>
```

The editButton/iconButton CSS sets the background-image and width/height.

Looking in Firefox element inspector (not firebug) the span has some events attached to it firing the ajax call to the server, so why haven't they been disabled?  Is this a bug in Wicket?  I only happened upon it because I tried to click on a link that looked disabled during a demo!

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well that seems to be a bug in the implementation of AjaxLink.
It will add an AjaxEventBehavior with the following implementation:

```
    protected AjaxEventBehavior newAjaxEventBehavior(String event)
{
    return new AjaxEventBehavior(event)
    {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Override
        protected void onEvent(AjaxRequestTarget target)
        {
            onClick(target);
        }

        @Override
        protected void updateAjaxAttributes(AjaxRequestAttributes attributes)
        {
            super.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
            AjaxLink.this.updateAjaxAttributes(attributes);
        }
    };
}
```

as you can see this implementation doesn't care that the `isLinkEnabled()` method has been overridden. Therefore the only workaround is to switch to `isEnabled()` this one will implicitly deactivate all childs of that component as well. (Depending on the nature of your `getSelectedLocation()` method I would advice to do that during the `onConfigure()` part of the component)

Comment: I agree. Wicket could be improved here. Please file a ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET and we will fix it. Thanks!

Comment: isLinkEnabled has been removed in Wicket 7 [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Migration+to+Wicket+7.0#MigrationtoWicket7.0-AbstractLinknolongeraltersitsmarkuptorenderitselfasdisabledWICKET-4904) and I would argue that if isLinkEnabled shouldnt be used it isnt necessarily a bug just poor documentation.

Comment: Well it's at least inconsistent. AjaxFallbackLink has a correct implementation for that for example. But since it's remove in Wicket 7 I decided against reporting it.

Answer (score 1):

To disable a link you should set `setEnabled(false)` on this link like this:

```
AjaxLink al = new AjaxLink("link") {

    @Override
    public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
        //do something on click
    }

    @Override
    protected void onConfigure() {
        setEnabled(someCondition());
    }

};
```

The method `boolean isLinkEnabled()` is just a helper as it's [JavaDoc](http://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/link/AbstractLink.html#isLinkEnabled%28%29) says:

> Helper methods that both checks whether the link is enabled and
>   whether the action ENABLE is allowed.

Comment: Thanks, it is down to isLinkEnabled vs isEnabled, but I would recommend overriding isEnabled rather than setting it in onConfigure

Comment: `isEnabled()` might be called multiple times during a request where as `onConfigure()` is called only once so it is recomended to set visibility and enabled in `onConfigure()`